# Integrate Instagram pictures to google maps

Tags: google-maps, instagram, google-maps-embed

I don't know if this is the place to ask for this kind of stuff but i'll try.

I want to integrate a map of google maps embedded in my website that shows my geotagged instagram pictures on it.

There are some online services but none is exactly doing what i need which is so basic at the same time.

I found a widget called [snapwidget](http://snapwidget.com/#getstarted) where you can manage to show your pictures in the map, but then you have no option to set the zoom of the map and the controls wont' appear.

Is there any way to show and set the zoom controls in a embedded google map which is not directly from google maps api?

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the [Embed API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#optional_parameters) you can set optional parameters for the zoom level and other settings.  I don't see anything to disable the controls, and I don't know about integrating with Instagram photos.

e.g.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view
  ?key=YOUR_API_KEY
  &center=-33.8569,151.2152
  &zoom=18
```

Answer (score -1):

SnapWidget is one option, but then there's also Widgetic and The Data Pack.
http://thedatapack.com/embed-instagram-map/